# Eventos não funcionam após disparados uma vez

Tags: javascript, jquery

estou fazendo um CRUD com JS e localStorage. Porém, quando faço uma inclusão ou uma exclusão, ao tentar clicar nos botões para isso os eventos não são mais disparados.

Podem me explicar o por quê?

```
var tblVariacoes = localStorage.getItem('variacoes');
var indice_selecionado = -1; //Índice do item selecionado na lista
tblVariacoes = JSON.parse(tblVariacoes);
if (tblVariacoes == null) {
  tblVariacoes = [];
}

$("#tbl-variacoes tbody").html("");
$.each(tblVariacoes, function(indice, valor) {
  var cor = JSON.parse(valor);
  $("#tbl-variacoes tbody").append("<tr>");
  $("#tbl-variacoes tbody").append("<td><a href='javascript:' data-index='" + indice + "' class='btn btn-default btnExcluir'>Apagar</a></td>");
  $("#tbl-variacoes tbody").append("<td>" + cor.cor + "</td>");
  $("#tbl-variacoes tbody").append("<td>" + cor.tamanho + "</td>");
  $("#tbl-variacoes tbody").append("<td>" + cor.modelo + "</td>");
  $("#tbl-variacoes tbody").append("<td>" + cor.qtde + "</td>");
  $("#tbl-variacoes tbody").append("</tr>");
});

function CarregaTabela() {
  $("#tbl-variacoes tbody").html("");
  $.each(tblVariacoes, function(indice, valor) {
    var cor = JSON.parse(valor);
    $("#tbl-variacoes tbody").append("<tr>");
    $("#tbl-variacoes tbody").append("<td><span data-index='" + indice + "' class='btn btn-default btnExcluir'>Apagar</span></td>");
    $("#tbl-variacoes tbody").append("<td>" + cor.cor + "</td>");
    $("#tbl-variacoes tbody").append("<td>" + cor.tamanho + "</td>");
    $("#tbl-variacoes tbody").append("<td>" + cor.modelo + "</td>");
    $("#tbl-variacoes tbody").append("<td>" + cor.qtde + "</td>");
    $("#tbl-variacoes tbody").append("</tr>");
  });
}

function Adicionar() {
  var variacao = JSON.stringify({
    cor: $("#slct-cores").val(),
    tamanho: $("#slct-tamanho").val(),
    modelo: $("#slct-modelo").val(),
    qtde: $("#cor-qtde").val()
  });
  //console.log(variacao);
  tblVariacoes.push(variacao);
  localStorage.setItem("variacoes", JSON.stringify(tblVariacoes));
  $(".opt-variacoes").hide();
  $("#slct-cores").val("").removeAttr('disabled');
  $("#slct-tamanho").val("");
  $("#slct-modelo").val("");
  $("#cor-qtde").val("");
  alert("Cor " + $("#slct-cores").val() + " adicionada com sucesso.");

  CarregaTabela();
  return true;
}

function Excluir(indice_selecionado) {
  tblVariacoes.splice(indice_selecionado, 1);
  localStorage.setItem("variacoes", JSON.stringify(tblVariacoes));
  alert("Cor removida com sucesso.");
  CarregaTabela();
}


$(".btnExcluir").click(function() {
  indice_selecionado = parseInt($(this).attr("data-index"));
  Excluir(indice_selecionado);

});

$("#bt-add-cores").click(function() {
  var cor = $("#slct-cores").val();
  $("#slct-cores").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  $(".opt-variacoes label").html(cor);
  $(".opt-variacoes").show();
});

$("#bt-save-cor").click(function() {
  Adicionar();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `jQuery` não faz uma varredura de todo o `DOM` sempre que um evento é disparado, por padrão. Então ao definir o evento de clique, apenas os elementos já existentes é que terão o evento vinculado.

Para resolver nesse teu caso é possível utilizar um único evento da seguinte maneira:

```
$(document).on('click', '.btnExcluir', function() {
  // Código de exclusão
});
```

Isso pode ser traduzido como "jQuery, olha pra mim o documento e sempre que um clique ocorrer, verifica se o elemento condiz com o filtro especificado e aí me avisa".

Answer (score 1):

Eu tive esse problema recentemente. Não consegui descobrir porquê mas achei um jeito de resolve-lo. O que estava acontecendo é que quando eu clicava no botão o jQuery dava unbind nos eventos, então eu fiz o seguinte. Sempre que ele clicava, dentro da função de execução eu dava o bind no evento novamente. Algo mais ou menos assim:

```
function Excluir($obj) {
    indice_selecionado = parseInt($($obj).attr("data-index"));
    tblVariacoes.splice(indice_selecionado, 1);
    localStorage.setItem("variacoes", JSON.stringify(tblVariacoes));
    alert("Cor removida com sucesso.");
    CarregaTabela();
    $($obj)..click(function() {
        Excluir(this);
    });
}

$(".btnExcluir").click(function() {
    Excluir(this);
});
```

Funcionou pra mim. Foi uma gabiarra, mas deu certo.